# want to get same output by SQL/TSQL what i am getting by the LINQ query

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq, t-sql

using LINQ i am query a data for sorting and i am getting right answer.

here is my data & linq query......please have look.

```
void Main()
{
List<SearchResult> list = new List<SearchResult>() {
    new SearchResult(){ID=1,Title="Geo Prism GEO 1995 GEO* - ABS #16213899"},
    new SearchResult(){ID=2,Title="Excavator JCB - ECU P/N: 728/35700"},
    new SearchResult(){ID=3,Title="Geo Prism GEO 1995 - ABS #16213899"},
    new SearchResult(){ID=4,Title="JCB Excavator JCB- ECU P/N: 728/35700"},
    new SearchResult(){ID=5,Title="Geo Prism GEO,GEO 1995 - ABS #16213899 GEO"},
    new SearchResult(){ID=6,Title="dog"},
};

var to_search = new[] { "Geo", "JCB" }.Select(x => x.ToLower()).ToArray();

var result = from searchResult in list
let title = searchResult.Title.ToLower()
let key_string = to_search.FirstOrDefault(ts =>  title.Contains(ts))
orderby key_string == null ? -1 :  title.Split(new[]  { key_string },  StringSplitOptions.None).Length descending 
group searchResult by key_string into Group
    orderby Group.Count() descending
select Group;

result.Dump();

}

public class SearchResult
{
public int ID { get; set; }
public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

my question is what sql query i need to write as a result i will get same output in sql server 2000.
suppose my data is stored in sql server table like this way

```
Table : MyTable
------------------
ID  Title
-----------
1   Geo Prism GEO 1995 GEO* - ABS #16213899
2   Excavator JCB - ECU P/N: 728/35700
3   Geo Prism GEO 1995 - ABS #16213899
4   JCB Excavator JCB- ECU P/N: 728/35700
5   Geo Prism GEO,GEO 1995 - ABS #16213899 GEO
6   Maruti gear box #ABS 4587
```

### MY Edit

i fix some syntax issue in ur sql....just have look

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split] (@String varchar(8000), @Delimiter char(1))     
returns @temptable TABLE (items varchar(8000))       
as       
begin       
   declare @idx int       
    declare @slice varchar(8000)       

    select @idx = 1       
        if len(@String)<1 or @String is null  return       

   while @idx!= 0       
   begin       
       set @idx = charindex(@Delimiter,@String)       
       if @idx!=0       
           set @slice = left(@String,@idx - 1)       
       else       
          set @slice = @String       

       if(len(@slice)>0)  
           insert into @temptable(Items) values(@slice)       

       set @String = right(@String,len(@String) - @idx)       
       if len(@String) = 0 break       
   end   
return       
end

DECLARE @Sterm varchar(MAX) 
SET @Sterm ='GEO JCB'
;WITH SearchResult (rnum, title)
as 
(   
(select 1 as rnum,'Geo Prism GEO 1995 GEO* - ABS #16213899' as title)
union all
(select 2 as rnum,'Excavator JCB - ECU P/N: 728/35700' as title)
union all
(select 3 as rnum,'Geo Prism GEO 1995 - ABS #16213899' as title)
union all
(select 4 as rnum,'JCB Excavator JCB- ECU P/N: 728/35700' as title)
union all
(select 5 as rnum,'Geo Prism GEO,GEO 1995 - ABS #16213899 GEO' as title)
union all
(select 6 as rnum,'dog' as title)
) 

select rnum, title from SearchResult
join 
( select lower(Items) as term 
  from dbo.Split(@Sterm , ' ')
) as search_terms
on lower(SearchResult.title) like '%' + search_terms.term +'%'
order by 
search_terms.term,
(select count(*)
from dbo.Split(lower(SearchResult.title),' ')
where Items = search_terms.term
) desc
```

but it is not full filling my requirement.

1) query should return search term and as well as those rows also at end which has no relation with search term.

2) second sort should be there like those rows will come first where search term found maximum time like GEO & JCB.

u miss second order by descending based on occurrence of search term. if u see the image very properly then u can see what kind of out put i was asking here. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it with SQL alone.  You will need a stored routine to split the title string into substrings, then SQL can count the substrings that match your search.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split] (@String varchar(8000), @Delimiter char(1))     
returns @temptable TABLE (items varchar(8000))       
as       
begin       
  declare @idx int       
  declare @slice varchar(8000)       

  select @idx = 1       
    if len(@String)<1 or @String is null  return       

  while @idx!= 0       
  begin       
    set @idx = charindex(@Delimiter,@String)       
    if @idx!=0       
       set @slice = left(@String,@idx - 1)       
    else       
       set @slice = @String       

    if(len(@slice)>0)  
      insert into @temptable(Items) values(@slice)       

      set @String = right(@String,len(@String) - @idx)       
      if len(@String) = 0 break       
    end   
  return       
end

DECLARE @Sterm varchar(MAX) 
SET @Sterm ='GEO JCB'
;WITH SearchResult (rnum, title)
as 
(   
    (select 1 as rnum,'Geo Prism GEO 1995 GEO* - ABS #16213899' as title)
    union all
    (select 2 as rnum,'Excavator JCB - ECU P/N: 728/35700' as title)
    union all
    (select 3 as rnum,'Geo Prism GEO 1995 - ABS #16213899' as title)
    union all
    (select 4 as rnum,'JCB Excavator JCB- ECU P/N: 728/35700' as title)
    union all
    (select 5 as rnum,'Geo Prism GEO,GEO 1995 - ABS #16213899 GEO' as title)
    union all
    (select 6 as rnum,'dog' as title)
) 
select term,rnum, title
  from SearchResult
  left join 
     ( select lower(Items) as term 
         from dbo.Split(@Sterm,' ')
  ) as search_terms
  on lower(SearchResult.title) like '%' + search_terms.term +'%'
order by 
  isnull(search_terms.term,'ZZZZZZZZZZZZZ'),
  (select count(*)
     from dbo.Split(lower(SearchResult.title),search_terms.term)
  ) desc, 
  rnum desc
```

Comment: suppose search term is stored in variable then what will be ur approach...because here u hard code the search term. suppose search term is like that Declare @Sterm varchar(MAX) SET Sterm ='GEO JCB' any help.

Comment: I added support for a variable for the search terms.

Comment: Of course, replace SearchResult with MyTable if you want to search a real table.  This will result in a full table scan for each term, though which will be very expensive.

Comment: thanks for ur sql....i copy & run ur sql in sql server then it is giving too many syntax error. can u please rectify the sql code. thanks

Comment: Did you create the dbo.split function from the example?  What syntax error are you getting?  I don't have a SQL server database to test.

Comment: i fix the syntax error in ur sql code. i update my question please have look at edit section.your sql is not full filling my requirement fully rather it meets partially. please have look at my update section.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14921/discussion-between-justin-swanhart-and-thomas)

Comment: thanks it works....can u please tell me why u write this line isnull(search_terms.term,'ZZZZZZZZZZZZZ') why ZZZZZZZZ what it does. what does it mean

Comment: MS SQL server sorts NULL as less than all other strings characters, so sorting by search_term.term will put the 'NULL' term for unmatched documents at the top.  ZZZZZZZZZ is greater than any other term so it will push the nulls to the bottom.

Comment: And you wanted the terms sorted in natural order (GEO before JCB) so you need to make nulls larger than any other value to put them at the bottom.  ORDER BY DESC search_term.term would list JCB, GEO, NULL which was not what you wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [SQL Server Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx) to grab the query that is being run.

Comment: i want that some will write the linq query in sql as a result i can run than query in sql server 2000 and get the above output. why u suggest me to use sql server profiler. when i need only sql.

Comment: Because Profiler will show you exactly what query LINQ is sending to SQL Server. This seems to fit your requirement precisely. You won't use Profiler all the time, it will just show you - once - how LINQ constructed the query you want to run.

Comment: i dont know how to use profiler to see what sql is generated. can u guide me. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ featires to grab SQL query:

```
var ctx = new SomeDbDataContext();
var sw = new StringWriter();
ctx.Log = sw;

var items = from item in ctx.INVENTTABLEs
            where item.ITEMID.Length < 10
            select item;

foreach (var item in items)
{
   Console.WriteLine("{0}", item.ITEMID);
}

Console.WriteLine(sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString());
Console.ReadLine();
```